# How to Convert the existing stack to nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I have a single stack with two instances RDS,EC2.I have to follow the structure that has root stack and two nested stack RDS,EC2.

Following should be the structure

1.Root stack

2.Webserver stack: All services related to EC2

3.DB stack: All services related to RDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **general procedure** would be as follows:

1. **Extract** rds and ec2 resources to its own template files (e.g. ec2.yaml, rds.yaml)
2. **Parameterize** ec2.yaml and rds.yaml, as well as add `Outputs` section to them. The `Outputs` are needed if you want to reference their return values in the Root stack.
3. **Upload** the ec2.yaml and  rds.yaml into S3.
4. In the **root stack** create two resources of type `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`, i.e. one for rds and one for ec2. Use [TemplateUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-templateurl) to provide paths to locations in S3 (step 3). Use [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-parameters) to define input parameters created in step 2.
5. Use [GetAtt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) to **reference outputs** of the nested stack in the root stack.

Comment: and how can i use this cmd ->aws cloudformation package --template-file package/cloudformation.yml --output-template-file package/cloudformation-output.yaml.can you elaborate more how to package the template i am very new in aws.